# Merge [ms-extensions-logging] and [microsoft-extensions-logging], but which one to keep?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I suggest to merge the tags [ms-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-extensions-logging) and [microsoft-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-logging).

Both are for the same package/usage ([docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging))

I'm doubting which one we should keep:

- [microsoft-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-logging) is more readable IMO
- [ms-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-extensions-logging) has more questions (16 vs 4) and has a tag info
- We have also [microsoft-extensions-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-caching) and  [microsoft-extensions-dep-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-dep-injection), and there are no other `ms-extensions-...` tags.
- Currently there is a mix between ms and Microsoft tags, examples: [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word), [ms-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel) and [microsoft-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-graph)
- I think both tags has the same quality of questions

I think [microsoft-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-logging) is better, but like to hear others :)

*Good to know: the tag (on of the both) has really value, as [nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlog) + [microsoft-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-logging) is really a different question than only [nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlog). Also [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) + [nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlog) is likely to be [microsoft-extensions-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-extensions-logging), but not necessary.*

Comment: I agree, `ms-extensions-logging` and `microsoft-extensions-logging` both are for the same package. That should be merge

Comment: What should I do to get the tags merged?

Comment: As you have a score of >=5 on that tag, you can suggest a tag synonym.

Comment: True, but synonym != merge